# Where has this question gone to?

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

A question was asked a few hours ago and is showing as migrated:

> [image]

Clicking on the [link to the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396784/is-stackoverflow-gdpr-complaint) returns a 404.

The 404 page states "This question was voluntarily removed by its author."

Where has this question gone to?

If it has really been removed by the author why is it still appearing in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?

Comment: The question was deleted. But it was previously migrated from this meta to meta.se. The original post (before migration) still exists on this side, but takes you directly to the deleted post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was deleted by the post's author after migration. It had already been closed as a duplicate of

- [Brace yourselves: The GDPR is coming!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310321/brace-yourselves-the-gdpr-is-coming)
- [We’re Updating The GDPR-Related Sections Of Our Legal Portal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346206/we-re-updating-the-gdpr-related-sections-of-our-legal-portal)

So presumably the OP was satisfied and didn't think leaving the duplicate on the [global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) would be useful. The -5 score there may have hastened that decision.

The stub here will be [automatically deleted in 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/188189). It is left for that time in case the author wishes to edit it to be on topic here on MSO given that the migration has basically failed.

Answer (score 1):

The original question was posted on MSO, but the link redirects to MSE, meaning it was migrated there.

The fact that the link resolves to a 404 error means that the question was subsequently deleted there.

Comment: I thought migrated questions normally left behind a stub, which show where it was migrated to and who migrated it? "This question was migrated to xxxxxx because ... Migrated x hours ago by xxxxxx:?

Comment: @DavidPostill they do... I migrated it to MSE... I don't have enough rep on MSE though to see what happened there after though

Comment: @JonClements So I guess the OP deleted both the migrated question and the stub ...

Comment: *shrugs* - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396784/is-stackoverflow-gdpr-complaint is still here it seems

Comment: @JonClements I get a 404 when I click through to that link. I wonder why it's visible to you. Perhaps https://shouldiblamecaching.com/ ?

Comment: @Mureinik I don't have enough rep to see the deleted stub anyway. You should be able to though.

Comment: @DavidPostill you'd need 10K on MSE.